# Make thunderbird store all mail locally for IMAP accounts but not indexing all for search

Tags: thunderbird, search, imap

In Thunderbird the global *gloda* search is connected to the selection of downloaded/syncronized folders of the IMAP accounts in the Offline-settings.

Is it possible somehow, that Thunderbirds download/syncs all emails in the IMAP account but does not add them to the index for the global search?

I would like to do this because I have some accounts that I only keep in thunderbird for archiving reasons but I don't want to find those mails, when I use the global search

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could install a **PortableThunderbird** instance in another folder and use that instance for those accounts that you don't want to be searched in your active Thunderbird.

Then you should remove those accounts from your active Thunderbird and [rebuild the global search database](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database)